# Tab bar app loading first tab view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, view, tabbar

I created a tab bar application with storyboards.

Regardless of which tab is selected, I want to activate a specific tab when an event occurs (such as an error).

I have tried the following example but with no success:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Is there another way to manage that?

Comment: When did you call `[_tabBarController setSelectedObject:0];`? Might be too early! Nevertheless, index 0 should be the first selected index anyway...

Comment: Julien I call it from another tab bar controller when I want to bring up to my first tab controller

Comment: Another tabBarController? Do you have your outlets connected properly? Do you call this method from another thread?

Comment: Imagine that I have four tabs in my tab bar app. For example, the fourth tab loads a web page in a webview. I implemented successfully the reachability and I want when the device loses it's connection to go automatically to the first tab. I hope to make you understand my thought.